# Java script code for ios local storage... if the data lasts

Tags: javascript, local-storage

First of all,
Please refer to this link.

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Here it says regarding iOS and saving cache:

> Safari Mobile stores localStorage data in the cache folder, which is subject to occasional clean up, at the behest of the OS, typically if space is short

How often do you think this will happen? 
Does this mean that if there is enough space in the iOS device, the above mentioned clean up is not going to happen?

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local storage will be cleaned if the user explicitly performs "clear website data". So it will generally be there all the time, but it can also be gone the next page reload. You need to design your application to handle this.

Comment: Hello! Thank you a lot for your answer..  I have already found a solution for the next page load problem. But is there a java code that somehow prevents the date from being cleaned even when the user performs clear website data? Thx!

Comment: No, you can't prevent the user from cleaning website data. It can also handle on for example upgrade of the web browser app.